# RMarkdown word_document bullet indent

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, pandoc

How can you intent a normal bullet list as Word would do when rendering from Markdown? By default it's left aligned.

e.g. instead of

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do ei

1. Item 1

would be come....

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do ei

tab tab tab  1. Item 1

Comment: you'll have to change your reference.docx

Comment: I am not sure that bullet points can be controlled by the reference file, as they technically are not a style. https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html. To me this doesn't seem possible, and highlights how that RMarkdown isn't really designed to have such fine tuning of the word template.